# How to know the Content-Type of the API response in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and I am calling GET API using fetch in react-native but sometimes the response `Content-Type` is `text/html` and sometimes response `Content-Type` is `application/json`.
I want to check the response `Content-Type` first before I do response.json().
I tried using try-catch but it displays a warning on the android screen when try case fail.

```
try{
return response.json();
}catch(e){

}
```

I also tried `response.ok` but it checks for response code instead of a content type.

What's the correct way to know the `response` `Content-Type`?

UPDATE(Answer):

```
if(response.headers.get("Content-Type").indexOf("application/json")>=0){
  
    //Response is in JSON

 }else{
         
    //Response is in text/html

 }
```

Comment: It gives `undefined`. However when I do `JSON.stringify(response.headers)` in the string there is `"content-type":"application/json" `

Comment: Posted one answer, take a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.get(param)` on response headers.

```
response.headers.get("Content-Type")
```

As fetch will give you response with headers object. You can simply get it from headers object.

Comment: It gives appliication/json; charset=utf-8.

Comment: And then I checkd like this. `response.headers.get("Content-Type").indexOf("application/json")>=0`

Comment: Glad this helped you.

Comment: @ArchitSandesara, can you post the code that worked for you successfully in your question ?